# Copy, Paste Values, Save As "Filepath. Only For Worksheets with a value greater than 1

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate a process. We receive a report that has multiple companies billing information. We currently paste this report into an excel document and it filters out to individual worksheets for each separate company.

We have a macro that copy, paste values to a new worksheet and saves the file. The problem is that the macro saves a file for every worksheet in the excel file and I want to adapt the macro so that it only saves the file where there is billing information for that month.

Therefore we don't have new worksheets saved down, with no billing for the customer.

Currently the macro is set up as below for every customer worksheet.

eg:'BGNBINS

```
Sheets("BGNBINS").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

'Save the new workbook and close it

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "G:\ACCTG RV\Breena's Admin & JDE\Weighbridge Reports (Breena)\3rd Party Tonnes\Customers 3rd Party\06.2015\BGNBINS 0615 WTS.xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

'CONSOLW

```
Sheets("CONSOLW").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add

'Paste special values and formats

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

'resize to fit gridlines
    Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'save and close file in specified drive and name

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "G:\ACCTG RV\Breena's Admin & JDE\Weighbridge Reports (Breena)\3rd Party Tonnes\Customers 3rd Party\06.2015\CONSOLW 0615 WTS.xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks I only have tried the coding posted above, I'm wanting to know a code that will only copy and paste worksheets that have values greater than 1 for billing into a new worksheet and save. 
 There is a cell reference in each worksheet tab that calculates the total billing value, so could reference a cell number in the VBA coding?

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you are a bit vague on how the sheet works but is this what you are after?

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("a1") > 0 Then
      'Save the new workbook and close it
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="File Path", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook,   CreateBackup:=False
      ActiveWorkbook.Close
End If
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you so much for your comment and sorry about the vagueness, there are about 50 worksheet tabs, each tab has it's own unique customer code as the worksheet name. The macro is currently set up to repeat the same code but the worksheet name being unique and filename being that of the "worksheet name MM/YY".

Comment: I need a macro, that copies all sheets with a1 > 0, paste value and saves as .."Worksheet name and "mm/YY".

Comment: OK I will have a look tonight for you